# Welcome to Q&A for [your text here]

Tags: discussion

The current welcome banner reads:

> Welcome to Q&A for passionate videogamers on all platforms -- check out the [FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq)!

[image]

This sounds a bit awkward and forced to me:

- is "passionate" really necessary (do we have a problem with unpassionate videogamers asking questions)?
- is "on all platforms" really necessary?

The goal of the welcome banner is to explain in a few words what the site is.  On all the Stack Exchange sites, this follows the format of "Welcome to Q&A for...", which seems to work on most sites:

- Stack Overflow: Welcome to Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers
- Server Fault: Welcome to Q&A for system administrators and desktop support professionals
- Super User: Welcome to Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users

These work because they identify a "tribe", and I immediately know whether I'm part of that tribe of not ("I *am* a professional programmer", "I *am not* a system administrator").

The problem with "Q&A for passionate videogamers on all platforms" is that I don't really feel like "a passionate videogamer on all platforms".

So what's a better tagline / description?

Comment: I think it sounds doofy with the Welcome to Q&A "Welcome to Gaming! A Q&A site for [...]"

Comment: @Marco I'd definitely agree with this...if we had a real domain name. "Welcome to Gaming" sounds a bit odd

Comment: So why can't we have nice things like a real domain name? :(

Comment: @RavenDreamer Domain names are overrated

Comment: @Raven stay tuned...and if you have any good ideas, send them our way

Comment: ""Welcome to Q&A for...", which seems to work on most sites:"  Just because it works for other sites doesn't mean it works for this one, does it?  I think the whole wording is a bit too formal than I'd like.  It may work for more 'professional' oriented pages like SO, but gaming is supposed to be informal and fun, imo.

Comment: I don't like people the "_loving_" word choice. I'd much prefer _passion_, because it implies the passion for reaching _mastery_, and reaching _mastery_ of what we do is why we're here in the first place.

Comment: @badp "mastery" is not the first word I think to associate with "passion".

Comment: I like the 'on all platform's line, actually.  Think we should keep that.

Answer (score 8):

> Welcome to Q&A for people who love playing video games

alternative wording (Juan Manuel)

> Welcome to Q&A for people who love to play video games

Comment: "love to play" has a nicer sound to it IMO

Comment: @JuanManuel It also decreases the number of words with more than one syllable!

Comment: I do prefer the second version as well.

Comment: "love playing" sounds more natural to me.

Comment: "Love playing" is undoubtedly more common (natural) in some dialects for casual conversation, but I agree with Juan that "to play" simply sounds nicer.  Perhaps some English.SE people should weigh in? :P

Comment: English grammar says that "playing" is correct here. Also, I'd replace "love" with "like".

Comment: @BlaXpirit What are you talking about?  Full infinitives can be used as noun phrases. A gerund may be more natural, as already noted, but it's no more "correct".

Answer (score 6):

> Welcome to Q&A for people who love video games

Answer (score 6):

...why not just:

> Welcome to Q&A for video-game enthusiasts

?

Comment: You raise in important point: video game, videogame or video-game?

Comment: The way I've heard it argued in the past, "video game" is most technically correct, but "videogame" is often preferred by those who wish to argue that video games are more than superficially different from board or party games. While I don't think I'd ever use "video-game" in a sentence by itself, it makes a decent modifier of "enthusiasts".

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Gaming SE - All the gaming, none of the flaming

(Referencing the unfortunate fact that most other forums discussing gaming have more flame wars than they do actual content)

Comment: Clearly, your mother was a hamster and your father smelt of elderberries.

Answer (score 3):

```
Welcome to Q&A for computer and console gamers
```

... as opposed to, you know, RPG.SE and Boardgames.SE ...

Comment: the message should be geared towards brand new users, not people familiar with the network (they'll figure it out on their own)

Comment: @DavidFullerton Video games is a slightly archaic term, but it does encompass these two, and includes stuff like old coin-ops etc.

Answer (score 2):

> Welcome to the Q&A for passionate videogamers

Comment: +1 for adding "the" before Q&A, which was the main thing bothering me about the message.

Comment: @Strix This bugs me a lot as well. I was under the assumption that they (SE as a whole) weren't using the Q&A bit as a noun, rather just shorthand for "Questions and Answers." `Welcome to Questions & Answers for passionate videogamers` *does* make a bit more grammatical sense (though still doesn't sound very nice, imo), but if you're using "Q&A" as a singular noun, then I agree, it definitely doesn't fit without an article.

Comment: I don't think I can get behind "Welcome to the questions and answers…".  :-|

Comment: @Ben I agree that it should read "Welcome to the Q&A _website_", but... it's kinda obvious it's a website, rite?

Comment: Should be `video gamers`, two words.

Comment: @CyberSkull I dunno. I can make moderately strong points on each of the two changes to the current wording I made - if "Q&A" is shortand for "questions and answers website" then the 'the' is pretty much required; if it's "questions and answers" then it probably needs to be pluralized to be clearer; as it is it just reads wrong. As for removing "on all platforms", well, it'd be more accurate to say "on any platform" (do you need to have _all_ the platforms?), but then you might as well say nothing. As for "videogamers" or "video gamers"... meh! There's no risk of confusion at hand there.

Comment: I am a stickler for `video game` and derivatives being two words. They were shoved into one word by some hack after nearly 30 years of being two words.

Answer (score 2):

Something slightly different?

> Welcome to Gaming.SE: a Q&A site for gamers by gamers.

Comment: Too cliche in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

> Welcome to Q&A for gamers of all platforms

Comment: Are gamers on a platform or of a platform?

Comment: @Fredley Gamers aren't on a platform. **Games** are *on* a platform.

Comment: "I am gaming on a PC" vs "I am gaming of a PC"?

Comment: Ok I asked at english.SE, I'm wrong...

Comment: @fredley that's apples to oranges, friend.

Comment: Perhaps correct, definitely archaic (at least in my dialect).

Comment: So do I need to own _all_ the platforms to be here?

Comment: @badp ಠ_ಠ... really?

Comment: @Raven Hey, the potentially confusing test is the reason behind one of the two word changes I proposed. So it's a big deal for me!

Comment: How about `any` platform?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not an easy answer, I bet there will be a great deal more improvements in the near future if we ever agree on just one greeting. So how about this?
"Welcome one and all to Q&A about the video games you play!" or maybe something simple like:
"Greetings and welcome to gaming!"